# Scala initialize a constructor called more than once

Tags: scala, constructor, initialization

I have a simple class in Scala. I want to init some data when class is created. This is my code:

```
class SomeClass(someSeq: Seq[Int]) {

    val someMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[Int, Set[String]]

    init()

    def init(): Unit = {
      println("init")
    }

    override def getData(aValue: Int): Set[String] = {
      println("I was called")
    }
}
```

And the code that runs it:

```
def someClass = new SomeClass(a)
for (i <- 1 to 3) {
  someClass.getData(i)
}
```

This is the output:

```
init
init
I was called
init
I was called
init
I was called
```

The code in "Init" initializes "someMap".

For some reason, the Init method get called every time I call the method "getData". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "the Init method get called every time I call the method "getData"." No, it doesn't. Or if you think otherwise, post complete code that shows it does.

Comment: Yes, it does. I updated to show the code.

Comment: No, it doesn't. See my answer.

Comment: Well, it does, but... because I am stupid... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def someClass = new SomeClass(a)
```

your `def` defines a method. Invoking the method calls `new SomeCLass(a)`.

```
for (i <- 1 to 3) {
  someClass.getData(i)
}
```

Your for loop calls the `someClass` method three times. Each of those invocations calls `new SomeClass(a)`. The constructor calls `init` each time. `someClass` then returns the new instance, and `getData` is called on that.

So it's not calling `getData` that causes `init` to be called. It's calling `new SomeClass(a)`

Try

```
val someClass = new SomeClass(a)
```

instead. That will call `new SomeClass(a)` once and assign the result to `someClass`.

Also, your posted code doesn't even compile (because getData's body doesn't return the correct type)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for troubling. Still in the process of learning... :)

Comment: It's worth stopping to think when the impossible seems to be happening to see what else might be going on :) If it looks like the constructor is getting called multiple times, probably the constructor is getting called multiple times :-P

Comment: The code could compile if println had the correct type, but the misplaced override is irrefutably non-compilable.